# Spark Garbage Collection Tuning - Reduce Memory for Caching using spark.memory.fraction - Why?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I was going through the book Spark The Definitive giude for Garbage Collection Tuning where it says that

> If a full garbage collection is invoked multiple times before a task completes, it means that there isn’t enough memory available for executing tasks, so you should decrease the amount of memory Spark uses for caching i.e. spark.memory.fraction

Also the Spark documentation says,

> If the OldGen is close to being full, reduce the amount of memory used for caching by lowering spark.memory.fraction; it is better to cache fewer objects than to slow down task execution
> (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning)

**Question -**
Why should we reduce spark.memory.fraction to reduce the memory for caching?
Shouldn't we reduce spark.memory.storageFraction which is the amount of storage memory immune to eviction, expressed as a fraction of the size of the region set aside by spark.memory.fraction?

Answer (score 0):

THere is a relationship between the two:

- spark.memory.fraction expresses the size of M as a fraction of the
  (JVM heap space - 300MB) (default 0.6). The rest of the space (40%)
  is reserved for user data structures, internal metadata in Spark, and
  safeguarding against OOM errors in the case of sparse and unusually
  large records.
- spark.memory.storageFraction expresses the size of R
  as a fraction of M (default 0.5). R is the storage space within M
  where cached blocks immune to being evicted by execution.

So this is really like the course tuning knob and the fine tuning knob.  But... But... In practice, for performance tuning, I would start by tuning the code, and then the # or partitions, and then consider thinking about tuning configuration settings.   I hope your are following that path first before digging into the minutiae of these settings.  They come in handy but only when you've done the rest of the work to get to them.